# Transactions do not appear in Ethereum mempool

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, txpool

I analyzed my node mempool for one hour. Only 60% TX included in blocks(during this one hour) appeared in my node mempool. Why I don't see other 40%??? Node configuration? Hardware? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum mempool is not universal. Your mempool varies greatly from that of a different node due to how your node sources its mempool data. The validators of these questioned blocks on average shared 60% of the same transactions but due to discrepancies, as expected, 40% weren't logged by your node. In other words, because Etherum nodes have variable mempools, queued transactions in the validators node will complete but some in your que may be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, guys. Yes, I know mempool is not universal and that there are private transactions, but 40% missing transactions is too much. 
Is there anything I can do to get more tx in my node mempool, maybe better node server, like more RAM or to better node configuration, like changing something in config.toml file? Or this is max nodes can get in mempool?

Comment: I am unaware if Geth has the option, I checked earlier and couldn't find it, for a number of reasons I would recommend switching to a different execution client, but for the purpose of txpool monitoring Nethermind is great, I personally use it and it provides the option on boot to expand the mempool to a custom size as well as determine what txpool imports are permitted. The link to these options is as follows: (look under txpool tab)  https://docs.nethermind.io/fundamentals/configuration/  P.S Client diversity is great, would highly recommend nethermind over Geth.

Answer (score 0):

> Only 60% TX included in blocks(during this one hour) appeared in my node mempool.

Because of [Malicious Extractable Value, users cannot use the public memory pool](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/mev) on Ethereum anymore. Otherwise [they will lose a lot of money of their trades to malicious Ethereum validators](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1726327741283516696).

Instead, users use paid centralised private mempools that have made a trust-based paper contract with the block producers to include their transactions without leaking them to the public.